# Space between items in custom listview

Tags: android, listview

I created a very basic custom `listview` but as you can see in the images, there is a big space between items in it.
I don't know where is my fault.

My xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <CheckBox
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/list_item_crime_solved_checkBox"
  android:padding="4dp"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/list_item_crime_title_TextBox"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_item_crime_solved_checkBox"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:padding="4dp"
  tools:text="Crime Title"/>
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/list_item_crime_date_TextBox"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_item_crime_solved_checkBox"
  android:layout_below="@+id/list_item_crime_title_TextBox"
  android:padding="4dp"
  tools:text="Crime Date"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is a photo?

Comment: Where is the image? If you want to remove spacings, try removing padding and check if parent layout has extra margin or padding.

Comment: change height of relativeLayout from match_parent to wrap_content

Comment: @Massoud set layout_height to wrap_content.

Comment: It seems looking change when you check your `check box` ? If you talking about space between `Text View` then remove `padding` from `Text View`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the layout you've posted here is used to inflate for each item on the list_view. So, set the `layout_height` of the relative layout to `wrap_content`.